# How to automatically create a service connection in azure devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-cli

I would like to automatically create a service connection in azure devops. Ideally either with terraform or azure cli. I would like to do this as part of an azure devops pipeline using 1 of the above methods. Is this possible? If so how? ... I did not see any docs talking about this but it seems like you should be able to do it instead of using the UI. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can automatically create a service connection using the az cli and the [az devops service-endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/service-endpoint?view=azure-cli-latest) command. Use an Azure CLI task to use this in an Azure DevOps pipeline.

Alternatively, in Terraform, you can use [azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest/docs/resources/serviceendpoint_azurerm)